# Android new Application (registration process)

Tags: android

I built an android application that registers the user with its username/Password/phoneNumber.

if the user is registered in the DB, he can see the other menus for the application.

How can i check if the user is registered or not on the application ? There is a good way to do that (propose the registration process or application menu) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use JSON method you'll have to add php file in order to send the data from the android application to your database ( you'll make an Insert into for a registration or just a Select for an existing user in you php file) then JSON method take back the data to android and return TRUE or false I know it's vague but there's lot of tutorial on this method. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you mean by "how can I check if the user is registered" when you just said the information is stored in a DB.

So... Based on the information you provided, you can do a couple things:

1. Check the DB to see if the user exists / is registered.
2. Use SharePreferences to store a variable saying whether or not the user has registered and then acting based on that information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html